# Compare 2 systems using pairwise preferences

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

I have systems A and B. I sample N inputs $X_i (0 \leq i<N)$ and run them through each system, getting outputs $A_i$ and $B_i$ for every $i$. I also have a random vector $Flips_i \backsim Bernoulli(0.5)$.

I then survey K users in exactly the same way:

For each of the N following inputs, do you prefer the output on the left or the right?

if $Flip_i$: Present to user  $x_i$ | $B_i$ | $A_i$

else: Present to user $x_i$ | $A_i$ | $B_i$

Results are given in $K x N$ matrix $M$ where $M_{ij} = 1$ if user i prefers the output of system A for input j, else it is equal to 0.

The null hypothesis is that users don't have a preference for system A or B.

What kind of test can I use to test this hypothesis?

If $K$ was 1, I think a binomial test would work but I'm not sure how to extend it to $K > 1$ users.

Comment: To clarify: so each of the $K$ users answers $N$ questions?

Comment: Yes, the same N questions are answered by each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a binomial mixed effects model?

Collapse the data from matrix form, into a $K\times N$ length vector.

Your model would be $\text{logit}(p) = \beta_0$ (where $p$ is the probability of picking output of A over output of B). Add a random intercept for user, under the assumption that each of the $K$ users might have inherently varying preferences for the output.

The direction and magnitude $\beta_0$ (you can use a formal hypothesis test if you want) will tell you of any preference (or anti-preference) of A over B.

Because of your Flip variable, we can effectively ignore whether A or B is presented to the user on the left or the right.